# Страница настроек приложения, как в ОС

Tags: android, java

Видел в некоторых приложениях, например, `model document viewer`, страницу с настройками с точно таким же видом, как и в самой ОС Андроид. Каким образом добиться такого же виде страницы? Или они просто вручную компируют, что вряд ли.

Пример:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальная [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). Суть проста - в xml файле описываете, какие нужны настройки (их названия, подсказки, типы, значения по умолчанию и так далее), а сама система берет на себя создание, отображение и сохранение настроек.

Comment: Всё получилось, только не могу найти, какой стиль надо применить, чтобы фон был с градиентом, как на картинке.